# What is the proper way to use Ember.js controllers in this scenario?

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js

I'm writing an `Ember.js` app to show a list of nested comments fetched from a CRUD RESTful API.

Half way through, I realize I'm probably misusing `Ember.js` and not taking advantage of its paradigms.

For instance, my `Comment` object looks like this:

```
App.Comment = Em.Object.extend({
  id: null,
  author: null,
  text: null,

  delete: function() { /* AJAX call to API here */ }
});
```

Is it alright to ha the `delete()` function as part of the model object, instead of a controller?

Another doubt I have is in my handling of states. In my template I do something like this:

```
{{#if view.comment.editing}}
    {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="view.comment.text"}}
    <a href="#" {{action cancelEditingComment}}>Cancel</a>
{{else}}
    <p>{{view.comment.text}}</p>
    <a href="#" {{action editComment}}>Edit</a>
{{/if}}
```

Then in my router, the `editComment` and `cancelEditingComment` actions will delegate to `Comment`, which has functions:

```
startEditing: function() { this.set('editing', true); }
cancelEditing: function() { this.set('editing', false); }
```

I can't help but think that I'm doing something wrong, although this kind of code seems to work.

Do you have any suggestions about how to reorganize my code, and any recommended reading that might help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experiences, your model shouldn't really have any business logic in it. It should just have a set of fields and maybe some computed properties if you have some complex fields that can be generated.

Your view delegating to your controller is definitely the right move for deleting. When it comes to editing though, seeing as it's only really your view that cares about this (typically), I'd be inclined to make `isEditing` part of the view itself. Then you can check this flag to decide whether to draw simple text or a textarea for input.

```
App.controller = Em.Object.create({
    comments: [],

    deleteComment: function(comment) {
        this.get('comments').removeObject(comment);
    }
});

App.CommentView = Em.View.extend({
    comment: null,
    isEditing: null,

    delete: function() {
        App.controller.deleteComment(this.get('comment'));
    },

    startEditing: function() {
        this.set('isEditing', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. I'm trying to move the `isEditing` logic from the `Comment` to my view, but the logic to edit is in my controller (as I think it should). And when I'm in the controller I can't do `this.get('view').set('isEditing', true);` What should I do? Perhaps change my router so that `actions` are delegated to views, and there, in turn, to controllers?

Comment: Adding `isEditing` to your view was based on the assumption that you were only changing how you were rendering it. Sorry, I should have been more clear. I'd probably just move that field back to your comment but be sure to set it from the controller instead of the model itself.

Comment: You assumption is correct: I *am* only changing how it's rendered, so I do believe that `isEditing` belongs to the view. Can you comment on whether I should delegate actions to views first, or controllers first, in my router?

Comment: You can't really delegate things *to* the view. Views should be in charge of rendering and nothing else. Any business logic that comes from clicking inside your view (like your edit and delete buttons) should be handled entirely within the view if possible (like in the case of `isEditing`) or delegated to your controller (like in the case of `delete`). You shouldn't really need a router in this case to control the varying states of your view.

Comment: In a way I don't need a router, because I'm not routing to pages or hash-URLs. I could do without a router, but then who catches the `{{action}}` helpers?

Comment: I can answer myself: `target="view"`. Source: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_action

Comment: Unless something has changed recently, you don't even need to define `target="view"` as that is the default.

Comment: The documentation says that it goes to the router by default, so I guess I do need `target="view"`.